# Apache mina SocketAcceptor and java.net.Socket communication

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, communication, mina

I m writing a network program to Apache Mina Tcp server and java.net.Socket client

Server Code

```
    SimpleIoProcessorPool<NioSession> pool = new SimpleIoProcessorPool<NioSession>(NioProcessor.class, 20);

    SocketAcceptor acceptor = new NioSocketAcceptor(pool);
    acceptor.setReuseAddress(true);

    // Add two filters : a logger and a codec

    acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast( "logger", new LoggingFilter() );
    acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast( "codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter( new TextLineCodecFactory( Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ))));
    acceptor.setHandler( new TimeServerHandler() );

    // Configurate the buffer size and the iddle time
    acceptor.getSessionConfig().setReadBufferSize( 2048 );
    acceptor.getSessionConfig().setIdleTime( IdleStatus.BOTH_IDLE, 1 );

    acceptor.bind( new InetSocketAddress(8001) );
```

And my server handler is ,

```
public class TimeServerHandler extends IoHandlerAdapter{

@Override
public void messageReceived( IoSession session, Object message ) throws Exception
{

    System.out.println("messagereceived");


    String str = message.toString();
    System.out.println(str);

    if( str.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("quit") ) {
        session.close(true);
        return;
    }

    Date date = new Date();

    System.out.println("Writing to client");

    session.write( date);
}
```

}

My Socket Client is

```
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        Socket socket = new Socket(inetAddress, 8001);

        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        bufferedWriter.write("Test");
        bufferedWriter.flush();

        System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());

        System.out.println("Done....");

        bufferedWriter.close();
        bufferedReader.close();
```

The problem is server socket doesn't communicate with java.net.socket.
Can someone say what is the wrong hear..

Answer (score 1):

in server code replace with this
LineDelimiter("$") "$" is decoding delimitter

```
 acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast( "codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter(new TextLineCodecFactory(Charset.forName("UTF-8"), LineDelimiter.DEFAULT, new LineDelimiter("$"))));
```

check this link
http://mina.apache.org/mina-project/userguide/ch9-codec-filter/ch9-codec-filter.html